# How to protect from fraud when giving out CVV

Tags: credit-card, australia, fraud, consumer-protection

In Australia, it seems like a common practice that when paying for something over the phone, the guy on the other side asks for the credit card number, expiry *and* the CVV number ! I have never had to give my CVV number ever before when making payments over the phone - as the amount of fraud that can be committed is obvious.

So my question is - How do I make sure I am not a victim of fraud when paying for services using a credit card over the phone ?

Will the credit card provider deny fraud protection in such a case where I have given out the CVV myself ?

I have denied giving out my CVV which has resulted in a denied service.

Comment: Did _you_ call the advertised number of the merchant when ordering, or were you responding to an offer from _someone who is calling you_ to sell you something and you were thinking that it sounds like a good deal? In the latter case, I wouldn't give out anything, not even the CC number, let alone the CVV number. Ditto if the call is _claimed_ to be from a charity that you have donated to in the past and are inclined to donate to some more, or from a cause that you would like to support: save the starving children, support a disabled vet, etc.

Comment: @DilipSarwate My experience has been with the former cases

Comment: @happybuddha, looking at it from the merchant's perspective - they're asking for CVV to reduce **their** risk of fraud. Their interchange fee is lower when CVV is provided by the customer - otherwise, they might be responsible for any fraud associated with a stolen credit card number.

Comment: Consider that you are no less protected giving out the CVV over the phone today as you were back in the days *before CVV existed,* when CC number and expiry date was all there was to give.  CC fraud was a thing back then, but people still gave out the CC number and expiry date over the  phone. All the same advice for avoiding fraud over the phone still applies today.  If you need any further reassurances, perhaps you should call your credit card provider and ask these questions directly to them.

Comment: I would try to avoid paying by credit card over the phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a misapprehension as to what the CVV is.

First off, every time you enter it into a website, you're "giving" it to someone, same as if you give it over the phone.  Maybe you trust that they won't store it, but why do you trust a website more than a person?  I don't.

The purpose of CVV is to have a second form of check for when you are performing a card-absent transaction (meaning the card is not physically in the hand of the merchant and not swiped or chip-read), to make it more likely that the person is actually holding the card. Using your card over the phone is one form of card-absent transaction, just like over the web.

It does *not* guarantee safety.  What it does, is has a second thing that the potential thief would have to steal.  So when a thief downloads a database of cards used at some merchant, for example, assuming that merchant followed correct practice they didn't also get CVV numbers - so they're more limited in where they can use the stolen card numbers.  The person asking it for the over-the-phone transaction is helping you out here: they're making it less likely that someone who has stolen your card number will be able to make a fraudulent transaction with them.

Beyond that, CVV isn't really offering very much protection.  It's certainly possible for someone, whether a person on the phone or a person behind a website, to take that CVV, write it down, and then misuse your credit card number and CVV.  That's not your fault, and it's nothing your credit card issuer is going to hold against you.

You can see some additional information in some articles, like [this one from AVG](https://now.avg.com/credit-card-security-code-cvv-safe-give-out/):

> You may also be asked for your credit card security code when processing a payment over the telephone. As with online transactions, it’s usually safe to do this – you just need to be sure that no one overhears the details you give out (so avoid public places when doing this).

Here's an article by [nerdwallet](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/issues-face-accept-overthephone-credit-card-transactions/) that discusses things from a business owner's perspective:

> **How can I mitigate the risk of fraud?**
>
> > ...
> >
> > Get all relevant information when taking down a customer’s credit card information — including card number, expiration date, CVV code and billing ZIP code. Also, make sure you get the customer’s name exactly as it appears on the card, including middle initial if applicable.

Consumerist discusses a case where you should *not* have to enter it - in person.  But it does include a comment from Mastercard confirming over-the-phone is considered normal:

> “It’s difficult to think of a reason why an employee would ask a customer to recite their CVC2 code for an in-store transaction,” the spokesperson said. “As you note, the codes were created to help authenticate cardholders for online and over the phone purchases.”

Finally, from the [Visa merchant agreement](https://usa.visa.com/dam/VCOM/download/merchants/card-acceptance-guidelines-for-merchants.pdf), some notes:

> Mail order/telephone order (MO/TO) and electronic commerce merchants must verify—to the greatest
>   extent possible—the cardholder’s identity and the validity of the transaction.

Mail/telephone order are treated identically to e-commerce, in this section.

> If available, use fraud prevention tools such as Card Verification Value 2 (CVV2)*, Address Verification
>   Service (AVS)**, Verified by Visa, and Visa Checkout. For more information visit www.visa.com.

Note the instruction for phone order (and even mail order!) to use CVV2.

> Ask for CVV2
>
> > The Card Verification Value 2 (CVV2)* is a three-digit security number printed on the back of Visa cards
> >     on the signature panel and helps validate that a customer is in possession of the card at the time of an
> >     order. (See Visa Card Features and Security Elements on page 26 in Section 2: Card-Present Transactions of this
> >     document.)

Of course, it's strictly prohibited to retain this information regardless of what type of merchant it is:

> A cardholder’s CVV2 may never be stored as a part of order information or customer data. The storage of CVV2 is strictly prohibited subsequent to authorization.

Answer (score 6):

> In Australia, it seems like a common practice that when paying for something over the phone, the guy on the other side asks for the credit card number, expiry and the CVV number !

That's just as common in the US.

> How do I make sure I am not a victim of fraud when paying for services using a credit card over the phone ?

Regularly log onto your card website and check for unknown charges.

> Will the credit card provider deny fraud protection in such a case where I have given out the CVV myself ?

Why should they, knowing that you have to give the CVV during phone transactions?

> I have denied giving out my CVV which has resulted in a denied service.

Completely understandable, seeing that a person who doesn't know the CVV is highly likely to be doing something criminal.

The problem is that you seem to think that the CVV is a guaranteed shield against fraud, when **it's just one layer** of protection.

Comment: I have *never* given out my CVV in the US

Comment: I have.  Just the other night, I had to.

Comment: I live in the US too, and I don't think I've had a single transaction in the last year where it wasn't required (phone and online).